# What is Minority Carrier Storage Time?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, semiconductors

I know that Minority Carrier Life-Time is the time difference Between generation of minority carrier & their Recombination. I am bit Confused Between  Minority Carrier Storage Time &  Minority Carrier Life-Time, are they same thing or Different.

Comment: -1 for being too lazy to spell out whatever "b/w" and "B/w" are supposed to mean.  No, it's not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are two differents things.

**Minority carrier life-time** is the time for electron and hole concentrations, changed for any cause (radiations temperature, etc.), to return to their equilibrium concentrations.

**Minority carrier storage time** is stricly related to junctions.  The well know  Space-charge region act like a capacitor, and the stored charge are minority carrier, in both P and N regions. 
In steady state the diffusion phenomena are terminated and we have electrons stored in P and holes in N region. If I apply a voltage I change this charge accumuled to the spatial charge region until it reach anoter equilibrium state. Then if I change the bias the charge stored change another time. 
The time for the stored minority charge to become zero is called storage time.

See this picture, from the venerable *Millman - Halkias "Integrated Electronics"*.
[image: From Millman Halkias "Integrated Electronics"]

If you understand this for the p-n junction it is easy to apply to the mosfet channel region.